# Mongodb find not printing json data

Tags: node.js

In the code I am trying to find all documents with code UE19CS204.But in the console.log
a big message is printed not the JSON data.The findOne() is working but not find().
I don’t know what change to do to find all documents with code UE19CS204.

```
var MongoClient = require(‘mongodb’).MongoClient;
var url = “mongodb://localhost:27017/”;
MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true } ,function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db(“pes”);

dbo.collection(“course”).find({“code”:“UE19CS204”}, function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);

});
dbo.collection(“course”).findOne({code:“UE19CS204”}, function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
db.close();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `find()` creates a cursor for a query that can be used to iterate over results from MongoDB, see [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find).
Use `toArray()`, you can finde the documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#toArray).

```
dbo.collection(“course”).find({“code”:“UE19CS204”}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(docs);
})
```

Full example:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 
// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
// Database Name
const dbName = 'pes';
// Collection Name
const collectionName = 'course';
// Filter
const filter = { 'code': 'UE19CS204' }
 
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  client.db(dbName).collection(collectionName).find(filter).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(docs);
    })
  client.close();
});
```